# Block touches on anything when custom pop-up is shown

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

The user can upload data to a server in my Swift 5/Xcode 12.4 app by clicking a button in the navigation bar. While this is happening (asynchronously in a background thread) I'm displaying a custom pop-up and none of the regular buttons (including the buttons in the navigation bar) should be clickable:

```
static func showIndicator(view: UIView) {
    let parentView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
    parentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5) //red only for testing, going to be set to 0.0 later
        
    let indicatorContainer = UIView()
    let width = 80
    let height = 80
        
    indicatorContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    indicatorContainer.center = view.center
    indicatorContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.97)
    indicatorContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    indicatorContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        
    let indicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.large)
    indicatorView!.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height/2)
        
    indicatorContainer.addSubview(indicatorView!)
    parentView.addSubview(indicatorContainer)
    view.addSubview(parentView)
    indicatorView!.startAnimating()
}
```

Called from the `UIViewController` with:

```
Toaster.showIndicator(view: self.view)
```

This makes it impossible to touch the buttons,... in the regular `UIView` but it doesn't cover the navigation bar and the user could theoretically start the upload process a second time (amongst other things), which isn't good. I found two ways to prevent this from happening:

1. Disable the buttons in the navigation bar temporarily with `uploadButton.isEnabled = false`. This has the disadvantage that the buttons turn grey.
2. Cover the whole area, including the navigation bar, with an invisible `UIView` but this also covers the status bar and I'm not sure if it's okay to simply access the window like that:

   ```
    static func showIndicator(view: UIView) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })!
        let parentView = UIView(frame: window.frame)

        ...

        parentView.addSubview(indicatorContainer)
        window.addSubview(parentView)
        indicatorView!.startAnimating()
    }
   ```

I know about `userInteractionEnabled` but you can't use it for `UIBarButtonItem`s and there are too many other clickable UI elements underneath the pop-up to disable all of them temporarily.

What's the preferred method for blocking button presses on anything (= underneath the pop-up view) in the app while something else that shouldn't be interrupted by user interaction is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question, take a look at view hierarchy

[image]

navigation bar items are in front of your Toaster, to cover the navigation bar in UIKit, you can add a custom view above the navigation bar using the window property of your app delegate. That's what most 3rd party 'toaster' frameworks such as MBProgressHUD do.

So the minimal change required to block every touch event behind the toaster is

```
    // instead of add parent view to view, add it to keyWindow
    // view.addSubview(parentView)
    parentView.tag = 999 // set a tag to remove the view from the window's subviews later
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
    window.addSubview(parentView)
    indicatorView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Thanks for the visualization! So basically option 2 in my list is the commonly used/best/preferred solution, even though it also covers the status bar? In the simulator I can still pull down the menu from the top when that "window" view is active but I haven't had the chance to test it on a real device yet, so I don't know if it blocks anything of the status bar that shouldn't be blocked. `keyWindow` is deprecated in iOS 13.

Comment: yes, key window or the new version’s window are the right solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this function, which checks all the views in a UIViewController, tries casting them to disable user interaction. you can add as many types as you wish.

```
func toggleEditEnabled(editAllowed: Bool) {
    for view in self.view.allSubviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = editAllowed
        } else if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = editAllowed
        }
    }
}
```

the function maybe used like this:

enable interaction: toggleEditEnabled(editAllowed: true)

disable interaction: toggleEditEnabled(editAllowed: false)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There are a lot of elements that are clickable in this `UIViewController`, that's why I decided against disabling everything (and then enabling everything again once the upload is done) and want to work with a transparent `UIView` that covers everything instead. `userInteractionEnabled` also isn't available for a `UIBarButtonItem`, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: the UIBarButtonItem can also be disabled, with .isEnabled = false and .tintColor = UIColor.clear to avoid the grey effect.

Comment: `UIColor.clear` makes the button completely invisible and with its regular color (e.g. `UIColor.red`) it just stays grey.

Comment: @Neph I guess the best option is like the other's said, to cover it up

Answer (score 0):

Adding a view on window is best UI solution.
From iOS 13, you can access the current `window` by [self.view.window](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622456-window)

Or try this faster, simple, stable solution like below.
Just create a flag variable in your ViewController,...

Ex: `var isUploading = false`

```
func uploadImage(done: @escaping (UploadedURL) -> Void) {

    if self.isUploading { return } // Block users from spamming
    self.isUploading = true // Start uploading here
    // Show your popup here
    
    UploadManager.current.upload(file) {[weak self] result in
        self?.isUploading = false
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Hide your Popup here
        }
        done(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mixed up my question with someone else's, I didn't ask for help or code for the actual upload.

Comment: @Neph Did u understand my answer?
I just try to show u how it works with some comments added to the code. To explain how FLAG works.
Using FLAG is one of the most popular and simple mechanics in programming.

If u want to add a modal dialog, use "window" instead of "viewController.view".
Using "viewController.view" to become a container of Modal Popup is a bad method. Because you want a full-screen modal popup so "window" is the best choice.

Comment: Yes, I understood your code but it fails to answer my question when you take into account that, as mentioned in both my question and in the comments, there are a lot of elements that are clickable in that ViewController that all shouldn't be clicked on while the upload is doing its thing - too many elements to disable/enable every time (or to use a flag on), that's why I asked for a UI solution that deals with everything all at once.

Comment: @Neph I mentioned both UI-solution and Logic-solution in my answer.